# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

Tags: scala, jackson

I have a library X which has a dependency on `jackson-module-scala` version `2.9.7`. It contains this object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val Mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
```

I excluded this dependency from the library X and my project uses `jackson-module-scala` version `2.10.3`. However, it seems like this version was intended to support backward compatibility since it still has a deprecated `ScalaObjectMapper` defined in the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental` module.

But I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper.$init$(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper;)V
```

Is this an issue with the backwards compatibility not being set up correctly?

Link to `ScalaObjectMapper` for `2.9.7`:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/jackson-module-scala-2.9.7/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper.scala

Links to `ScalaObjectMapper` for `2.10.3`:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/jackson-module-scala-2.10.3/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper.scala
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/jackson-module-scala-2.10.3/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/ScalaObjectMapper.scala

Or is this an issue with the way library X packages/assembles its dependencies?